# visual studio code debug thymeleaf

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, thymeleaf, vscode-debugger

I have a spring boot project with thymeleaf. I want to debug the thymeleaf html itself. VS Code is getting the breakpoints in the java code, but I don't now how to configure it to get the breakpoints in the .html files.

My launch file is like this. The project is running at https://localhost:8083.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Application",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "mainClass": "com.demo.Application",
            "projectName": "Application",
            "args": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "url": "https://localhost:8083",
            "port": 8083,
            "request": "attach",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any idea? Thanks